# How do I add a list of dictionaries to another list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm using a for loop to add a dictionary to a list of dictionaries (which I'm calling data_file), using data_file.append()

It works fine :) But then later I try to add some more dictionaries to data_file in another for loop and I use data_file.append() again and it doesn't work. It doesn't add those dictionaries to data_file

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I don't get an error. It just produces a file that only has the dictionaries from massage_generators. It doesn't take on anything from travel_generators.

I've even tried commenting out the first for loop, the one for massage_generators, and in that case it does add in the travel_generators dictionaries. It's like I can't use .append() twice?

Any help would be much appreciated please!

I'm sorry it's not very elegant, I'm only just learning this coding stuff! :)

Thanks

```
import csv
import copy
import os
import sys


generators = list()

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    root, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if root.startswith('Travel Allowance Auto Look up') and ext == '.csv':
      travel = filename

open_file = csv.DictReader(open(travel))
generators.append(open_file)    

travel_generators = generators[:]
massage_generators = generators[:]

data_file = []  # result will be stored here (List of dicts)


travel_remap = {'FINAL_TRAVEL_ALL':'AMOUNT'}
massage_remap = {'MASSAGE_BIK':'AMOUNT'}


for generator in massage_generators:
  for dictionary in generator:
    dictionary['PAYMENT_TYPE_CODE'] = 'MASSAGE_BIK'
    dictionary['COMMENT'] = 'Massage BIK'
    dictionary['IS_GROSS'] = 'FALSE'
    dictionary['PAYMENT_TO_DATE'] = '01/01/2099'
    dictionary['PAID MANUALLY'] = 'FALSE'
    for old_key, new_key in massage_remap.iteritems():
      if old_key not in dictionary:
        continue
      dictionary['AMOUNT'] = dictionary['MASSAGE_BIK']
      del dictionary['MASSAGE_BIK']
      if (dictionary['AMOUNT'] != '0' and dictionary['AMOUNT'] != ''):
          data_file.append(dictionary)

for generator in travel_generators:
  for dictionary in generator:
    dictionary['PAYMENT_TYPE_CODE'] = 'TRANSPORTATION_ALLOWANCE'
    dictionary['COMMENT'] = 'Annual travel allowance paid in monthly installments'
    dictionary['IS_GROSS'] = 'TRUE'
    dictionary['PAYMENT_TO_DATE'] = '01/01/2099'
    dictionary['PAID MANUALLY'] = 'FALSE'
    for old_key, new_key in travel_remap.iteritems():
      if old_key not in dictionary:
        continue
      dictionary['AMOUNT'] = dictionary['FINAL_TRAVEL_ALL']
      del dictionary['FINAL_TRAVEL_ALL']
      if (dictionary['AMOUNT'] != 'Not Applicable' and dictionary['AMOUNT'] != '0' and dictionary['AMOUNT'] != '' and dictionary['AMOUNT'] != '#N/A'):
          data_file.append(dictionary)


keys = ['EMPID', 'Common Name', 'PAYMENT_TYPE_CODE', 'CURRENCY', 'AMOUNT', 'EFFECTIVE_DATE',
        'COMMENT', 'PAYMENT_FROM_DATE', 'PAYMENT_TO_DATE', 'IS_GROSS', 'HIDDEN_UNTIL', 'PAID MANUALLY', 'PAYMENT_DATE']

bulk_upload = open('EMEA Bulk Upload.csv', 'wb')
dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(bulk_upload, keys, restval='', extrasaction='ignore')
dict_writer.writer.writerow(keys)
dict_writer.writerows(data_file)

print "Everything saved! Look up EMEA Bulk Upload.csv"
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Can you post your code?

Comment: Hi! I don't get an error, it just doesn't add anything the second time I ask it to append. I've added my code, sorry it's not very nice looking!

Comment: Before each `data_file.append(dictionary)` add one line with `print len(data_file), dictionary` and check whether it is printing the data you're awaiting.

Comment: This isn't solving your problem, but did you know you can do `if dictionary['AMOUNT'] not in ('Not Applicable', '0', '', '#N/A'):`

Comment: Oh thank you :) I thought there would be a better way to write that alright :)

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer that helps you -- you can only accept one, but you can upvote as many as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
open_file = csv.DictReader(open(travel))
generators.append(open_file)    

travel_generators = generators[:]
massage_generators = generators[:]
```

Your `travel_generators` and `massage_generators` lists are using the same open file to iterate over and get data; the problem with that is once the file has been iterated over once by the `csv.DictReader` in `massage_generators` it has been exhausted and you get no more data when you try to read it again in `travel_generators`.

Try this instead:

```
generators.append(travel)     # just the filename    

travel_generators = generators[:]
massage_generators = generators[:]
```

and then in your loops:

```
for filename in massage_generators:
    for dictionary in csv.DictReader(open(filename)):
```

Also, in your first loop where you are gathering filenames:  be aware that the loop is only saving the *last* filename that matches.  If that is your intention you can make it clear by adding `break` on the line after `travel = filename`.

Comment: Thank you! :) That solved my problem. Sorry, what a rookie error!

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided, `generators`, `travel_generators`, and `massage_generators` are all identical, and each contain the same instance of `open_file`. When you iterate `massage_generators`, you reach the end of the file. Then when you iterate `travel_generators`, there's nothing left to iterate in `open_file`.

At the very least, you could change the following line:

```
open_file = csv.DictReader(open(travel))
```

To:

```
open_file = map(None, csv.DictReader(open(travel)))
```

`open_file` is now a list and not a generator and can be iterated and re-iterated.

However, I would recommend you iterate through the file once, and build your two dictionaries, and write to a `DictWriter` instance in each iteration.

```
open_file = csv.DictReader(open(travel))
...
dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(bulk_upload, keys, restval='', extrasaction='ignore')
dict_writer.writer.writerow(keys)

for line in open_file:
    massage_dictionary={}
    massage_dictionary.update(line)
    ... # manipulate massage_dictionary
    dict_writer.writerow(massage_dictionary)

    travel_dictionary={}
    travel_dictionary.update(line)
    ... # manipulate travel_dictionary
    dict_writer.writerow(travel_dictionary)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :) One question about the solution. I see you're doing 'map' to csv.DictReader(open(travel)). Do we not have to define what map does? And what is the first argument supposed to do? It's in as None. Maybe this is opening up a whole bunch of things that I'm not familiar with. Thanks again!

Comment: The first argument to `map()` is a function which is applied to every item in the second argument, which must be an iterable. If `None`, then the identity function is assumed -- that is, it doesn't do any manipulation. It's identical to `open_file = [line for line in csv.DictReader(open(travel))]`